# How to stop Ideablade DevForce writing to C:\Program Files\AppName\debuglog.xml in Vista

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-vista, uac, devforce

I have an application that uses Ideablade Devforce as it's OR mapper. When the application starts up it wants to write to the debuglog.xml file in C:\Program Files\Application Name\ This works fine in Windows XP, but due to Vista's locked down write access to Program Files, the app throws and error.

Is there a way to stop Ideablade wanting to write to this file?

OR

Is there another place that is recommended to install applications that want to write to files in their install path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the logging file option to a blank string within the IdeaBlade.ibconfig file.

It mentions in the help that if you don't supply a path it will save the file in the application's directory, but if you don't even supply the filename it will not save it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

csjohnst is correct. Setting the logfile element to an empty string in the ibconfig file will suppress creation of the debuglog.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have your own directory under C:\ApplicationName
OR
Set write access during deployment to your C:\Program Files\ApplicationName folder.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to talk to Ward Bell ;)
(http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In IdeaBlade.ibconfig file set the logFile to the empty string:  e.g.,

```
<logging> 
    <archiveLogs>false</archiveLogs> 
    <logFile></logFile> 
</logging>
```